# Getting two Slickgrid tables side by side

Tags: javascript, css, slickgrid

How would I go about putting two slickgrid tables side by side? Right now, I'm simply creating two grids using grid = new Slick.Grid..., but I have to use hardcoded dimensions in CSS like:

```
#dynamic1 { /*this is grid one*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height:500px;
}

#dynamic2 { /*grid two*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 750px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height:500px;
}
```

Which is not fun. And it isn't dynamic. If possible, it would also be nice if I can get them side by side, with a combined width that expands to fill the ENTIRE browser window.

Edit: It's fixed! Here's the new code:

```
#dynamic1 {
float: left;
width: 49%;
position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height:500px;
}

#dynamic2 { /*grid two*/
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;

  top: 120px;

  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
position: absolute;
  **float: left;**
  top: 120px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height:500px;
}

#dynamic2 { /*grid two*/
   **float: right;**
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 750px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height:500px;
}
```

You just need to add a float left and float right. You can assign them whatever combination of widths that equals 100%. Example:

```
position: absolute;
  **float: left;**
  **width: 45%;**
  top: 120px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height:500px;
}

#dynamic2 { /*grid two*/
   **float: right;**
  **width: 55%;**
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 750px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height:500px;
}
```

Comment: wow, this almost works completely! one quick question, though: do you know a way to make it so that the scroll bar for dynamic1 appears on the right side of dynamic1? Right now, both scroll bars appear on dynamic2, which is confusing.

Comment: Wrap them both in one div would be my first guess. It's hard to tell exactly what you're talking about though. Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: Agh, wait! I just realized that it only works with left:750px; included. float: right; isn't actually working. Lemme tinker... edit: Great, now it's working!